# How to make API request from HTML select tags?

Tags: javascript, axios

I need help with this scenario, getting all data from multiple select tag
and use those data to send an API request.

I have these three select tags, and one button to send a request to a news API.
The user needs to select a value from those select tags to set data like "source" and "category".
Example: "https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.org/v2/top-headlines?source='+ source +' + '&category='+ cat +'&apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

Not sure if this the efficient way.
Below is my js code.

```
//global variables
var apiUrl = 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
apiKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
displayRequest = document.querySelector('.displayRequestData'),
requestBtn = document.querySelector('#runApi'), //Btn to display data
newsOpt = document.querySelector('#news-selection'), //news select tag
catOpt = document.querySelector('#news-category'); //category select tag


requestBtn.addEventListener('click', newsRequest); //onclick

function sourceSelected() { //news option
    var source = newsOpt !== null ? newsOpt.options[newsOpt.selectedIndex].value : 'the-next-web';
    var cat = catOpt !== null ? catOpt.options[catOpt.selectedIndex].value : 'general';
    return newsRequest(source, cat);
}

function newsRequest(source, cat) {
 axios.get(apiUrl + 'top-headlines?sources=' + source + '&language=' + cat + '&apiKey=' + apiKey)
        .then(function (response) {
            var reStringify = JSON.stringify(response);
            var rejson = JSON.parse(reStringify);

            if (rejson.data.status == 'ok'){
               console.log(rejson.data.articles[1].source.name); 
                //console.log(requestBtn);
            }          
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

By the way, i got this error 
VM7472:1 GET https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/v2/top-headlines?sources=[object%20MouseEvent]&language=undefined&apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: For some reason, other just hit the downvote button without comment. not helping though!

Answer (score 0):

When you add the event listener to call `newsRequest` via onClick, the first and only parameter that will be sent to that function is the `event` object. Therefore, the parameters of `source` and `cat` are not passed to `newsRequest` when they click on the button. (This is why your resulting URL has the [object MouseEvent] in it)

Instead, you might want to call your `sourceSelected` function in the `onClick` event which is fetching the current field values and then calling the `newsRequest` function.

Answer (score 0):

I play around with my code, it's working now.
Note: The news API I'm using not allowing me to mix some data like country, source and langauge. So I try things that only allowed for free account and it works.

```
requestBtn.addEventListener('click', sourceSelected); //onchange

function sourceSelected() { //news option
    var source = newsOpt !== null ? newsOpt.options[newsOpt.selectedIndex].value : 'en';
    var cat = catOpt !== null ? catOpt.options[catOpt.selectedIndex].value : 'general';
    return newsRequest(source, cat);   
} //end of sourceSelected

function newsRequest(source, cat) {
    axios.get(apiUrl + 'top-headlines?country=' + source + '&category=' + cat + '&apiKey=' + apiKey)
        .then(function (response) {
            var reStringify = JSON.stringify(response);
            var rejson = JSON.parse(reStringify);

            if (rejson.data.status == 'ok') {
                console.log(rejson.data.articles[1].source.name);
                //console.log(requestBtn);
            }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}//newsRequest
```